# Nested fetch, second one fails - React & GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, fetch, apollo

Here is how my app works: I fetch tweets from an API and write them locally in a json file in an Apollo Server. Then, I want to fetch those tweets from the Apollo server using GraphQL. Sadly, it seems that I can't chain a `fetch` and a `refetch` (from the Apollo GraphQL query). When I run the code below, I always get an error `Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.` (when I refresh after the error, the data are the right ones). However, if in my form I only request the first API, wait a few seconds and press a button like this one `<button onClick={() => refetch()}>Refetch!</button>` then it works.

Here is the code:

```
let data = <Query
query={gql`
            {
                twitQueries {
                    id
                    text
                    username
                    retweets
                    likes
                }
            }
        `}
        >
        { ({ loading, error, data, refetch }) => {
            if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
            if (error) return <p>Error</p>;

            const tweets = <div> my tweets </div>;

            return  <div id='formAndTweets'>
                        <button onClick={() => refetch()}>Refetch!</button>
                        <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            const username = this.state.username;
                            const controller = new AbortController();
                            const signal = controller.signal

                            fetch('http://localhost:5000/user/'+username+'/max/10', {
                                method: 'GET', signal: signal
                            }).then((res) => {
                                return res.json().then((data) => {
                                    this.setState({request: 'done'});
                                    return refetch();
                                });
                            }); 
                        }}>
                            <label htmlFor="username">Username: </label>
                            <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={(e) => { this.setState({username: e.target.value}); }}/>

                            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                        </form>
                        {tweets}
                    </div>
        }}
        </Query>
```

Why can't I do something like `fetch(...).then(() => { refetch() })` and how to solve this without having to wait and press another button?

Here is the screenshot of the network console: [image: https://gyazo.com/9903ad667d6ce4d7ab7c0a83e8f6e426]

UPDATE: It works with a public Apollo Server. So it must be something going on with mine but I can't find what. Here is the code:

index.js :

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'
import cors from 'cors'
import resolvers from './resolvers'

const typeDefs = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'model.graphql'),{encoding:'utf-8'})
const myGraphQLSchema = makeExecutableSchema({typeDefs, resolvers})

const PORT = 4000;

const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // enable `cors` to set HTTP response header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

// bodyParser is needed just for POST.
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({ 
    schema: myGraphQLSchema,
}));

app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
    endpointURL: '/graphql',
  }),
);

app.listen(PORT);
```

resolver.js :

```
var exec = require('child-process-promise').exec;
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)

//updated by the first API
const testJsonPath = 'tweets.json';

const resolvers = {
    MyQueryType: {
        twitQueries(root,args,context) {
            return readFile(testJsonPath).then(content =>{
                return JSON.parse(content);
            })
        }
    }
}

export default resolvers;
```

model.graphql

```
scalar Date

type TweeterQuery{
    id: String
    username: String
}

type Twit{
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    date: String!
    replies: Int!
    retweets: Int!
    likes: Int!
    geo: String
    mentions: String
    hashtags: String
    permalink: String!
    emoticons: Int!
    emoticonsStr: String
    replying: Int!
    replyingTo: String 
    text: String!
}

type Member{
    id: ID!
    login: String
}

type MyQueryType{
    twitQueries(id: ID):[Twit]
}

schema{
    query: MyQueryType
    #mutation: Mutation
    #subscription: Subscription
}

input TwitInput{
    author:AuthorInput
}

input AuthorInput{
    id:ID
    login:String
}
```

It really weirds me out because as I said it actually works when waiting a few seconds after the first `fetch`. I just can't grasp where the problem is from in my server.

Comment: There's no reason `fetch(...).then(refetch)` shouldn't work. Where are you seeing the "Failed to load resource" error? Can you see in your network tab which request is failing? Is the fetch call itself blowing up?

Comment: @DanielRearden the error appears after the first `fetch` is done. It's the GraphQL `refetch` that fails, the first one always go through. It's really weird since it should indeed work, on paper. I see the error in the console.

Comment: If you comment out the `refetch` call, does that prevent the error from being thrown? I'm not sure why chaining the promises would matter here, but you are missing a `return` in front of `res.json()` as well.

Comment: @DanielRearden I added the return and the result is the same. If I comment the `refetch()` there's no error thrown. As I said, I can comment it, submit my form, physically wait 2 seconds and click a button to refetch and it will work. However, if I emulate the JavaScript and click the button as soon as the first `fetch` is done, the error will be thrown. I don't understand why it needs that delay.

Comment: Here's a simple sandbox using your code, modified to use some public APIs instead of the ones in your question: https://codesandbox.io/s/8zn78k1qj0 The refetch works as expected. So whatever the issue is, it's most likely outside this code.

Comment: @DanielRearden You're right, I tried with a public Apollo Server and it works. I updated my post. Something must be going on with my server but I can't put the finger on it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186437/discussion-between-daniel-rearden-and-pioupiou1211).

Comment: @DanielRearden I solved the problem by creating from scratch a new Apollo Server (and not express). I have no idea what was the exact problem in the first place but it works now. Thank you for putting the finger on what was wrong!